# subspaces properties

Tags: matrices

Let $\{ w_1, ..., w_n \}$ be a subset of the vector space $V$ such that $L (S) = V$ and $S$ is linearly independent (called basis). Let $v$ be any non zero vector in $V$. Show that there exists $w_i$ such that the set

$$S_0 = \{ w_1, ..., w_{i − 1}, v, w_{i + 1}, ..., w_n \}$$

is also linearly independent and $L(S_0) = V$.

Comment: There appear to be bits missing from your post.  Please edit, **and read it carefully** before you resubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Since $v \in V = {\rm Span} S$, then there exists $x_1, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $v = x_1 w_1 + ... + x_n w_n$. This solution is unique by the linear independence of $S$. Furthermore, $v \ne 0$, so that $x_i \ne 0$ for some $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Let $S' = (S - \{ w_i \}) \cup \{ v \}$. We claim that $S'$ is a basis for $V$.

Linear independence of $S'$ is easily checked. Consider the equation $y_i v + \sum_{k \ne i} y_k w_k = 0$. Substituting $v = x_1 w_1 + ... + x_n w_n$ gives $x_i y_i w_i + \sum_{k \ne i} (x_k y_i + y_k) w_k = 0$. Since $S$ was linearly independent, there is a unique solution $z_i = x_i y_i$ and $z_k = x_k y_i + y_k$ if $k \ne i$. Therefore, $y_i = \frac{z_i}{x_i}$ and $y_k = z_k - x_k \left( \frac{z_i}{x_i} \right) = z_k - \frac{x_k}{x_i} z_i$ if $k \ne i$ constitutes a unique solution to the initial homogeneous equation.

That ${\rm Span} S' = V$ is also easy to see. Take $u \in {\rm Span} S'$. Then there exist $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $u = a_i v + \sum_{k \ne i} a_k w_k$. Substituting $v = x_1 w_1 + ... + x_n w_n$ gives $u = a_i x_i w_i + \sum_{k \ne i} (a_i x_k + a_k) w_k$, showing that $u \in {\rm Span} S = V$. And given $u \in V = {\rm Span} S$, then there exist $b_1, ..., b_n$ such that $u = b_1 w_1 + ... + b_n w_n$. Then, note that $u = \frac{b_i}{x_i} v + \sum_{k \ne i} \left( b_k - \frac{x_k}{x_i} b_i \right) w_k$, showing that $u \in {\rm Span} S'$.